# Assigning value of pointer through argument

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a constructor to a struct e.g

```
struct MyStruct{
    int age;
    string name;
    MyStruct_Two * link;
    Mystruct( int age , string name , MyStruct_Two temp){
       this -> age  = age;
       this -> name = name;
       this -> link = temp;
    }
}
```

What i want to do , is to create `vector<MyStruct> v` which will hold these structs. But each struct will have pointer to another struct in another array.

I have created a function to make it real  =

```
vector<MyStruct> v
vector<MyStruct_Two> v_two
void AddStructToStruct( int age , string name ,vector<MyStruct> &v , vector <MyStruct_Two & v_two ){

   MyStruct_Two temp( age , name );  // create struct 

   v.push_back( MyStruct( age , name , *temp ) ); // put pointer as arg
   v_two.push_back( temp );
}
```

This throws:

> error: no match for ‘operator*’.

I have tried to put reference and even pointer to reference. I am not very much experienced in working with pointers , so i cant figure out how to do it clearly.

How can i assign value of pointer through argument?

Comment: I suggest you try some simpler code to better understand pointers. Drop the templates and the classes. Your problem has nothing to do with those.

Comment: You cannot have `this -> link` point to something that is created on stack - `MyStruct_Two temp( age , name );`. Once you exit the function call `AddStructToStruct` , `temp` will be destroyed and `this->link` will be pointing to an invalid memory location. You can create `MyStruct_Two` on heap by calling `MyStruct_Two temp= new MyStruct_Two( age , name );` and then pass pointer to temp to constructor of `MyStruct`. Note that you will have to handle the deletion of heap memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&` to take some objects memory address but...

Pushing into a vector copies (or moves) the object. So the pointer will dangle after exiting the function scope.

If you change to this:

```
vector<MyStruct> v
vector<MyStruct_Two *> v_two
void AddStructToStruct( int age , string name ,vector<MyStruct> &v , vector <MyStruct_Two *> & v_two ){

   MyStruct_Two *temp = new MyStruct_Two( age , name ); 

   v.push_back( MyStruct( age , name , temp ) );
   v_two.push_back( temp );
}
```

This will probably work like you want, but you also have to `delete` all the objects later.

Comment: how can i delete them? I tried delete[] v_two and even loop v vector and delete its link property didnt work

Comment: ```delete[]``` only works for arrays. My suggestion would be to loop through ```v_two``` and call ```delete``` on each element.

Comment: it didn not delete it , valgrind still shouts that memory hasnt been freed.

Comment: It does delete is though, valgrind might be getting confuse because you don't do it from the same context. If you have access to c++11 you could use ```std::unique_ptr<MyStruct_Two>``` and move into the vector, that way you don't have to worry about deleting, it will get done when the vector is deconstructed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107632/discussion-between-jorn-vernee-and-trolkura).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, you should stop and try to learn how to use pointers correctly.

Your variable temp is not a pointer, it is the structure itself, so you can't dereference it with the * operator. A possible change to make this part of the code correct would be this:

```
struct MyStruct{
    int age;
    string name;
    MyStruct_Two * link;
    //temp here is a pointer now and expects a address to point to as a parameter.
    Mystruct( int age , string name , MyStruct_Two *temp){
       this -> age  = age;
       this -> name = name;
       this -> link = temp;
    }
}
void AddStructToStruct( int age , string name ,vector<MyStruct> &v , vector <MyStruct_Two & v_two ){

   MyStruct_Two temp( age , name );  // create struct 

   v.push_back( MyStruct( age , name , &temp ) ); // pass the address of the structre.
   v_two.push_back( temp );
}
```

Not sure though it is a good idea to pass a reference of a variable created locally to a struct.

I usually prefer to use pointers instead of & and create a dynamic allocation so everything points to the heap and not to variables in the stack.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to insert a pointer to a local variable into a container.  The local variable goes out of scope, and now you're storing a dangling pointer.

Comment: Andre Kostur, as I pointed. The idea here was to teach him why his code is not compiling. "Not sure though it is a good idea"  can be read as a polite way of saying its a bad idea. 
That said, you can use it if the scope in which you use the container is inside the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD use shared_ptr instead of raw pointers. It will really prevent you from many bugs related to pointers lifetime.

```
vector<MyStruct> v
vector<shared_ptr<MyStruct_Two>> v_two
void AddStructToStruct( int age , string name ,vector<MyStruct> &v , vector <shared_ptr<MyStruct_Two>> & v_two ){

   shared_ptr<MyStruct_Two> temp( new MyStruct_Two(age, name) );

   v.push_back( MyStruct( age , name , temp ) );
   v_two.push_back( temp );
}
```

And I feel that it would be better to use shared pointers for MyStruct as well.